# Recover database when mistakenly ran nodetool decommission

Tags: cassandra

By Mistake I ran nodetool decommission because of which I cannot see inside /var/lib/cassandra folder. How can I recover this? any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover by adding it  again. before adding you must clear all the data on removed node and add into the cluster.